# Are there any research value in visible light communication?

Tags: digital-communications

My advisor wants me to take the area of visible light communication as my MS project, but I don't know whether there are any research value in this area, it seems most of the tenichnical difficulties are solved in this field. Any one has similar experience in this field? thank you !

Comment: It's good that you're asking yourself this question!

Comment: I don't have first-hand experience in that field but there's a lot of research going on and I highly doubt that all problems in VLC have already been solved.